# How to add a good email in sendgrid api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I'm sending some emails via sendgrid and nodejs. I have a content to sent, but i'm unable to add a good body like below

Body:

> Hi
>
> You are receiving this email as a reminder to enter time for the day.
>
> Best Regards, Operations Team

I'm able to send mail with the message only and couldn't find a way to add the "Best Regards,
Operations Team" lines. Please give an insight.

my code,

```
  sgmail.setApiKey(process.env.API_KEY);
      const msg = {
        to: '########', // Change to your recipient
        from: "######", // Change to your verified sender
        subject: `Reminder for Time Entry`,
        text: "Hi You are recieving this email as a reminder to enter time for the day.",
        html: "<h1> Hi You are recieving this email as a reminder to enter time for the day.</h1>",
    }
    sgmail.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain text you can add line breaks and they will display in the email. Note that you can use backticks (`) to write multiline strings in JavaScript. For HTML emails, you should wrap different lines in different paragraph (`<p>`) tags. Try the following:

```js
sgmail.setApiKey(process.env.API_KEY);

const textMessage = `Hi

You are receiving this email as a reminder to enter time for the day.

Best Regards, Operations Team`;

const htmlMessages = `<p>Hi</p>

<p>You are receiving this email as a reminder to enter time for the day.</p>

<p>Best Regards, Operations Team</p>`;

const msg = {
    to: '########', // Change to your recipient
    from: "######", // Change to your verified sender
    subject: `Reminder for Time Entry`,
    text: textMessage,
    html: htmlMessage,
}
sgmail.send(msg);
```

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks mate. was bit dry with docs.